# How to make a drop down list populate options

Tags: google-apps-script

I am setting up a Google Sheet that has a column for Make and a column for Model. I need to work so that when I choose a certain Make ONLY the particular Models will show up for that car.

```
function myFunction() {
   var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("19 - 20");
  var name = ["Acura"];
  var list = ["MDX","RDX","NSX","ILX","RLX","TLX"];

  var rule = SpreadsheetApp
  .newDataValidation()
  .requireValueInList(list)
  .build();

  ws.getRange("D3").setDataValidation(rule);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
function onEdit() {
  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var name = ["Acura", "Not Acura"];


  var rule = SpreadsheetApp
  .newDataValidation()
  .requireValueInList(name)
  .build();

  ws.getRange("B3").setDataValidation(rule);  

  model(ws);
}


function model(ss){
  var makeSel = ss.getRange("B3").getValue();
  var acura = ["MDX","RDX","NSX","ILX","RLX","TLX"];
  var notAcura = ["model1", "model2", "model3"];  

  if (makeSel == "")
    return 1;
  else if (makeSel == "Acura"){
    var rule = SpreadsheetApp
    .newDataValidation()
    .requireValueInList(acura)
    .build();

    ss.getRange("D3").setDataValidation(rule);
  }
  else if (makeSel == "Not Acura"){
    var rule = SpreadsheetApp
    .newDataValidation()
    .requireValueInList(notAcura)
    .build();

    ss.getRange("D3").setDataValidation(rule);
  }
}
```

It will change the model list based on the selection for the list, for testing this I just created an empty sheet and populated B3 and D3. This will cause the change to happen live (because of the `onEdit()`). You can add new lists for different makes and models, and you'll need to add the `else if` statements, but those will just be to add the code you posted in your question with the new name of the list.

Please let me know if this needs any clarification.